# Differentiating inequality

Tags: derivatives

So I was solving a question that goes as follows:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and satisfy
>   $$
> \left| f(x) \right| \leq x^4 + 5x^2\qquad \forall x
> $$
>   Show that $f'(0) = 0$

[image: Question]

T.P.T means to prove that

Now I know we can't differentiate the function due to  inequality. After some time when I was not able to solve the question I looked up the solution  on Youtube. The teacher there solved the question using a first principles method .

**My Doubt**

Isn't first principle same as differentiating a function . (Because this is how we prove the standard formulae ex F'(x) of sinx = cosx )

1. If we cant differentiate the function then how can we use first principle to solve this question?
2. Can this question be solved in any other way ?

Comment: Check out the squeeze theorem, noting that $f(0) = 0$ by the inequality.

Comment: What do you mean by *first principle*?

Comment: @dfnu https://brilliant.org/wiki/derivative-by-first-principle/

Comment: That's the just the definition...

Answer (score 1):

$|f(0)| \leq 0$ which means $f(0)=0$. Hence $|\frac {f(x)-f(0)} x| \leq |x^{3}+5x| \to 0$ as $ x \to 0$. Hence $f'(0)=0$ by definition of $f'(0)$.

Comment: but isn't this  same as differentiating f(x) as we are using first principle here ?